# Etherjs Transfer BNB Return 0 and doesnt end to Receiver Address

Tags: smartcontracts, web3js

Hi im new to smart contract. Im trying to code a simple transfer using etherjs and nextjs. Basically below are my code

```
import {ethers} from 'ethers';
const ContractAddr = '0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52'; /* BNB Contract address */
const ContractABI =[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]

const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();

let numberOfTokens = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.2', 18)
const Contract = new ethers.Contract(ContractAddr,ContractABI,signer)
const receiver = '0x8CA65A3Ce90d31a88FAa747c695183C2aefe537f';

Contract.transfer(receiver, numberOfTokens).then((transferResult) => {
            console.log(transferResult)
            alert("sent token")
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('error',error);
          });
```

on my metamask, it pops up as i wanted as follow :

[image]

however when i check the transaction details at the BSCscan Testnet, its showing 0 Value an the receiver is the Contract Address instead of the receiver.

https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x3278d9668391eee98aadf83e8ae58a0b999f2e9c3e5f47a21f504e1c04b24814

Help. Been stuck for a week searching high and low for similiar issue at Stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing together two different approaches - sending ERC-20 tokens and sending native currency of the network.

On the Ethereum networks, BNB is an ERC-20 token ([link](https://etherscan.io/address/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52) - mind the `0xB8c7...` address that you're using in your code).

However, on the BSC networks, BNB is the native currency. So you transfer it using native transactions - the same way as you would transfer ETH on Ethereum.

Assuming your code uses BSC provider:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);

const params = [{
    from: senderAddress,
    to: '0x8CA65A3Ce90d31a88FAa747c695183C2aefe537f',
    value: ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.2', 18),
}];

const transactionResult = await provider.send('eth_sendTransaction', params);
```

Comment: i tried ur code but it shown im transfering 1000 instead of 1000BNB. What happen if the user has other token in the metamask, would it took that token instead?

Comment: @MFuad My code doesn't show 1000 anywhere so I'm guessing you have put the 1000 in the `value` field. Mind that BNB has 18 decimals so that you need to put the large number including decimals as units. Either by manually entering `1000000000000000000000` to the `value` field, or by using the `parseUnits` function that adds the 18 zeros as well ([docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-parseUnits))... If they use a different network (with different native currency), then it would take the native currency of the network. You can validate that by specifying the `chainId`.

Comment: Great explanation @Petr Hajda. Many thanks!